# Eigenvalues of the product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be $m \times n$ and $n \times m$ real matrices.

I was asked to prove that if $\lambda$ is a nonzero eigenvalue of the $m \times m$ matrix $AB$ then it is also an eigenvalue of the $n \times n$ matrix $BA$ (I didn't have trouble showing that)

I need now to find an example showing that this need not be true if $\lambda = 0$

Answer (score 4):

Take
$$
A= \left( 
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
B= (
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1
\end{matrix}
)
$$

Comment: Can you detail a bit more ?

Comment: Well, $AB$ is a 2x2 matrix of rank $1$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $AB$, but $BA = (2)$ has only one eigenvalue, which is $2$.

Comment: Also, when $m=n$, $AB$ is invertible if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are invertible, so this example is about as general as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 \\
   0 &  1 \\
   0 &  0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 &  0 \\
   0 &  1 &  0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
then
$$
A B =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 &  0 \\
   0 &  1 &  0 \\
   0  & 0 &  0
\end{matrix}
\right)
\quad
B A =
\left(
\begin{matrix}
   1 &  0 \\
   0 &  1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
and
$$
\mbox{eig}(A B) = ( 0, 1 , 1)
$$
which includes the eigenvalue $0$, but
$$
\mbox{eig}(B A) = (   1,  1 )
$$
has only $1$ as eigenvalue.